# What role does political science play in philosophical understanding?

Tags: hegel, philosophy-of-history, idea, philosophy-of-political-science

If Hegel's Absolute Spirit drives the history of humanity to a certain ends, the historical political circumstances and decisions would be the most vivid representation of the Absolute Idea in action?

Hitler coming to power, Trump losing the election, Mao Zedong turning China to the West. Can we consider these events as a representation of Intelligent Design?

Comment: I do not see the link between Hegel's philosophy of history and Intelligent Design.

Comment: @JoWehler - I do not mean the more narrow meaning of "Intelligent Design" like Darwin's theory of evolution.

Comment: Evolution and survival of the fittest in human history.

Comment: The term "Intelligent Design" has a fixed meaning. It does not apply to Darwin's theory of evolution.

Comment: Re. "What role.."? : Political science gets very psychological and philosophical in terms of identity, for example. In turn, political science as science of *polis* (urban life) informs philosophy on how identity can relate to urban life.

Comment: @JoWehler - "... life on earth is so complex that it must have been designed by a supernatural entity" - this is applied to biology. How would you apply the term "Intelligent Design" to philosophy?

Comment: I think philosophy influences political science more than the reverse, though politics may define which philosophical positions are voiced.